# Generating new output filenames in for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, filenames

I want to write many raster files using a for loop.

```
path <- "D:/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/FolderD/"
files1 <- c("FolderE1/raster.tif", 
            "FolderE2/raster.tif", 
            "FolderE3/raster.tif")
files2 <- c("FolderF1/raster.tif",
            "FolderF2/raster.tif",
            "FolderF3/raster.tif")


for (i in 1:length(files1)) {
  raster1 <- raster(paste(path, files1[i], sep = ""), band = 1)
  is.na(raster1[[0]])

  raster2 <- raster(paste(path, files2[i], sep = ""), band = 1)
  is.na(raster2[[0]])

  mosaicraster <- mosaic(raster1, raster2, fun = mean)
  NAvalue(mosaicraster) <- 0
  outputfile <- paste(path, "mosaics/", files1[i], sep = "")
  writeRaster(mosaikraster, outputfile , type = "GeoTIFF", datatype = "INT1U", overwrite = TRUE)


  print(c(i, "of", length(files1)))
}
```

How do I create for each file a new folder within `"D:/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/FolderD/mosaics/"` which includes `FolderE1/, E2/... etc.` plus the filename, e.g. `mosaic.tif` ?

```
outputfile <- paste(path, "mosaics/", files1[i], sep = "")
```

Does not give a satisfying result.

Comment: The language I'm using is R

Comment: I don't follow all the details of what you want, but I am pretty sure if you want to create a directory `dir.create()` is your friend.

Comment: But how to include it in the code to generate directories automatically? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Just for clarification: You want to create a folder in "mosaics/" that is called "raster.tif" (e.g. files1[1]). **OR** do you like to create the folder "mosaic/" that contains the files with the films you set in files1?

Comment: the latter. I want to create a folder for each `mosaics/FolderE1/` `mosaics/FolderE2/` (etc.) which then contain the `raster.tif`-mosaics calculated in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to demonstrate one method of making folders within a loop: If you have the directories in an object just looping over the elements of that object.

```
folders1 <- c("FolderE1", 
            "FolderE2", 
            "FolderE3")




for(i in folders1)
{
  dir.create(i)              #creates a dir named after the ith element of folders1
  setwd(i)                   #goes into that directory
  tiff('raster.tif')         #plots your picture
  plot(rnorm(10,rnorm(10)))
  dev.off()
  setwd('../')               #goes out to the original folder 
}
```

Just a warning: this is all a bit dangerous because mistakes can make a big mess.